# Matching a quantifier of 1 or less

Tags: regex, tcl, hl7

I have a line of text that will contain several tilde characters (~).  In this scenario, I am working with a string of data that is a report.  Each tilde represents a line break/carriage return.  What I need to do is match only the single tildes (so that I can then turn them into spaces).  I want to leave the groups of multiple tildes as is.  I am able to match groups of multiple tildes (using `~{2,}`) However, I basically need to match the opposite of that.

Here is a sample of text I am trying to modify:

> FINDINGS:~~VASCULAR: The IVC~~~ ~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~, and portal vein appear
>   normal. The aorta is normal in~calibre without~aneurysm

In this example, I would like to match all 3 tildes that are not in a group of other tildes.  The "real world" data will contain many tildes throughout - with the possibility of some being at the beginning and/or the end of the string.  They may be surrounded by both spaces or characters.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set new [regsub -all {(^|[^~])~([^~]|$)} $str {\1 \2}]
```

---

Now that I have some time, some words.

We're looking for a tilde that is not preceded by a tilde and is not followed by a tilde. We could try this: `{[^~]~[^~]}` that does exactly that. However, that expression requires that there actually be a character before and after: what if the single tilde we're looking for occurs at the beginning or the end of the line? So, we want:

- the beginning of string OR a non-tilde character `(^|[^~])`, followed by
- a tilde, followed by
- a non-tilde character OR the end of string `([^~]|$)`.

We need to use capturing parentheses to remember what characters occurred before and after the tilde that we're turning into a space, so the replacement string is `{\1 \2}` == the character captured by the first set of parentheses, then a space, then the character captured by the second set of parentheses.

We Tcl users are lucky to have the regex engine we have. It is highly performant and very feature-full.

Comment: While this may answer the question - could you add a bit of explanatory text to help explain your answer?

Comment: i agree. It's Good Form to provide explanation of what you are doing with this code and why and how it solves the original problem. Don't forget that Stack Overflow is filled with newbies - and what may be obvious to you would not be to them. They could learn a thing or two from your expertise :)

Comment: @TarynEast: "Stack Overflow is filled with newbies" that need at least to read a regex tutorial and to search before asking a question in a forum. I don't see anything difficult or that needs to be explained in this answer.

Comment: No. Just no. The newbies on stack overflow don't know that they need to read a regex tutorial, and just assuming they should do that before reading your answer is not kind to them, and leaves them out in the cold. You were a newbie once too. There was a time where you didn't know a regex when you saw one - and didn't know what you'd need to read in order to learn what it was and whether the code written here would solve your problem.

Comment: Just today I helped a kid in 7th grade on this site. People like this are *welcome* on this site. They are just learning. They need you assistance and your experience, not your irritability. Please be kind and explain what you're doing. Also - the reason why I commented on your answer at all, is that your answer popped up in the "low quality" review queue... even Stack Overflow's bots think you need to add more explanation to your answer, and it is the policy of this site to require that you do. You'll also note that I am not the only (or even the first) to point it out to you. So please do it

Comment: @TarynEast, you're right to encourage better explanations. Sometimes during the day I just have time to dash off a quick answer.

Comment: and that's fair enough - me too :)

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman!  I inserted the regex into my script and it worked perfectly.  Thanks also for the explanation - I definitely learned something new.  I greatly appreciate the time you took to help me out!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Didn't realize TCL doesn't allow lookbehinds. Glenn's answer seems to have it covered though.

You could try this. Just uses negative lookbehind and lookahead to make sure the tilde isn't preceded or followed by another tilde.

```
(?<!~)~(?!~)
```

Test [here](http://regex101.com/r/mS9bW1/1).

Comment: Nope. Tcl does not have lookbehinds (Tcl uses its own regex implementation, not PCRE): http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm

Comment: Thanks @CodyProbst!  I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question!  It was correct except for that pesky tcl business.  ;-)